# How to make nested for loops using nested try/except to check if there is a list to iterate?

Tags: python, for-loop, try-except

How can I use try in nested for loops, so when my function would not have list of elements to iterate through, than it would go for the next loop that is nested. So something like this:

```
value = []    
list1 = None
list2 = [1,2,3]
list3 = [1,2,3]
try:
    for i in list1:
        for j in list2:
            for k in list3:
                value.append(i+j+k)
except:
    pass
```

Would change to this after the first try:

```
try:
    for j in list2:
        for k in list3:
            value.append(j+k)
except:
    pass
```

and if list2 was also `None` it would move to this:

```
try:
    for k in list3:
        value.append(k)
except:
    pass
```

Do I have to repeat and make several nested loops with `try:/except:` or there is some way to make it look cleaner than the code below?

```
value = []    
list1 = None
list2 = [1,2,3]
list3 = [1,2,3]
try:
    for i in list1:
        for j in list2:
            for k in list3:
                value.append(i+j+k)
except:
    pass
try:
    for j in list2:
        for k in list3:
            value.append(j+k)
except:
    pass
try:
    for k in list3:
        value.append(k)
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do, but for your use case, I suggest you something like that:

```
from itertools import product

value = []    
list1 = None
list2 = [1,2,3]
list3 = [1,2,3]

lists = [list1, list2, list3]
lists = [_list for _list in lists if _list is not None]
values = list(product(*lists))
```